# How to dynamic add Google analytics track code using php?

Tags: google-analytics

I would like to add track code for each link of in my email content
So , i have register a google analytic accounts and found that there is only 1 track code

therefore, how to use php , given a google analytics id and password given,

1. register for a new track code
2. add each code to a link (need to use php to add a 1px * 1 px image for each link?)
3. Return the codes added

Thank you

Besides, if i have to track the result  in Google analytic (traffic source ->campaign) or i can use an api that can integrate the result panel in Google analytic to my system ?

Thank you again for any kindly help

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [PHP-GA](http://code.google.com/p/php-ga/), it's a server side client for Google Analytics which should allow you to track links programatically.